# Render HTML tags on Microsoft word

Tags: html, cpu-word

I am trying to display HTML tags(eg: **bold text**) from the database to Microsoft word as formatted(**bold text**). it would be great if anyone can help me out how to render HTML tags to the word.

Thanks in advance.

Best,
Keerthi

Comment: Save the text as a `.html` file. You should be able to open it with MS Word.

Answer (score 0):

You Render HTML to a word document using Python and PyWin32, you can find the link here https://github.com/orf/HtmlToWord

HtmlToWord currently supports the following HTML tags:

Typography
p
b / strong
br
em
i
u
h1/2/3/4
pre